# Comment theming question

Tags: 7, theming, comments

In Drupal 7, when theming the comments in my website (comment.tpl.php), I want to print the comment title without a permalink wrapped around as a link. I want the raw title. This should be simple, it seems, but it seems there is no variable for that. `print $title` will show the title wrapped with the permalink link.

Do I have to mess with template.php to fix that?

I also tried `render($content['subject'])`, but nothing it is printed on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation of comment.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.tpl.php/7), you should have access to $comment, so the following should work:

```
<?php print $comment->subject; ?>
```

Comment: It does not work. Actually, $comment->title is an array. Drupal prints "Array".  But it is probably a good beginning. I had found that documentation too... Do you know how to  go from there and get the raw comment title? Thank you.

Comment: I meant to write $comment->subject, sorry. Anyway, I suggest you install devel.module if you haven't already. Then, you can simply do dpm($comment) and it will print all available keys in that object.

Comment: Hi, thanks fot the hint... The $comment->subject also prints "Array", so I probably have to get some part of that array. I have Devel installed, although I am sometimes confused on the number of variables and interfaces in the Devel module... I cannot find the comment >> subject track, for example. Do you know where to find the comments? Can I find it in "Field info"? Thank you.

Comment: `print $comment->subject;` works for me.

Comment: ok, it works, you are right, I probably did something wrong when testing the first time... Thank you!